Два роутера на один мэссэдж
такой вот вопрос. хочу считать общее количество сообщений, отправленный в чатах с ботом и записывать их в БД, для этого сделал роутер на все сообщения, но в таком случае, если отправляется сообщение с какой-то командой, то оно не работает, так как роутер на все сообщения его уже поймал. можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы было несколько роутеров, которые позволили бы это реализовать и как это должно выглядит в коде? заранее спасибо. aiogram версии 3

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/middlewares.html#middlewares
